# ufw blocking port I allowed

Tags: networking, server, docker, ufw

I have a docker application running on port 5402 in an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

```
36f81500c742   the/easytaxserver:latest   "dotnet EasyTax.Serv…"   6 hours ago   Up 6 hours   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5402->443/tcp, :::5402->443/tcp   easytaxcontainter
```

when the ufw is disabled it works fine. when I enable it blocks the port, even after i allowed it.

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5401                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5402                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5402/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5401 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5402 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5402/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

5402/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
5402/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

log I got when i called https://192.168.1.42:5402/api/TaxZones

```
Apr 14 03:41:23 nest kernel: [597114.647424] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens160 OUT=docker0 MAC=[omited] SRC=192.168.1.100 DST=172.17.0.3 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=43134 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56888 DPT=443 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Why does it say DPT=443, not 5402? how do I configure my server to fix this issue?

Comment: ufw is only a frontend to iptables/nftbles (depending on your Ubuntu version) and ufw does more than you see with `ufw status`.